# Get the value in row i corresponding to the min value of row j

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix 2x1000. I need to get the value of row 1 that corresponds to the minimum of row 2. How can I do that?

This is my code. I need to get the value of row 1 of matrix k21.

```
clear all

counter=0;
grid=0.0001;
k21=zeros(2,1/grid);

for i=(0:grid:1)

counter=counter+1;
k0=1; % Initial cake
T=20; % Time periods
beta=0.95; % Discount factor
delta=0.1; % Depreciation rate
k1=i; % Guess
k21(1,counter)=i; % Save guess

    for t=[1:T]

    k2 = (beta*(1-delta)*k0-(beta+1)*k1)*(delta-1);
    k0=k1;
    k1=k2;
    k21(2,counter)=k2;

    end


end
```

Answer (score 0):

The `min`function returns the minimum element and its index.

```
>> A = [2 10 ; 4 1; 5 7]

A =

     2    10
     4     1
     5     7

>> [M, I] = min(A(:,2));
>> A(I,1)

ans =

     4
```

Comment: Thank you. But 4 is not the min of row 2...

Comment: nevermind, got it